# Why are *to_init[0] and *to_init not the same thing when dealing with pointers to pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

```
void initialize_char(char** to_init, char* source, int start, int end)
{

    printf("%p\n",*to_init[0]);
    printf("%p\n",*to_init);
}
```

I noticed that `*to_init` and `*to_init[0`] are completely different memory addresses. But as I understand it (which I'll need correcting):

Order of precedence means in `*to_init[0]`, `to_init[0]` comes first, then followed by the indirection operator. Technically speaking, doesn't subscripting `to_init[0]`, simply reference the pointer that is being pointed at by **to_init, and then wouldn't the use of the indirecrion operator simply allow me to access what's inside this pointer?

Thus shouldn't the aforementioned then be the same as `*to_init`?

Comment: You seem to be asking why **toinit and *toinit aren't the same.

Comment: So to_init[0] doesn't subscript what it's pointing to?

Comment: If you do  printf("%p\n",*to_init[0]); 
 printf("%p\n",**to_init); They should be same.

Answer (score 2):

`to_init[0]` is translated as `*(to_init + 0)` or just `*to_init`. Therefore `*to_init[0]` would be equivalent to `*(*to_init)` or just `**to_init`.

`to_init` is `char**`, which makes `*to_init` a `char *` and `**to_init` to a `char`.

This means that *to_init[0] is giving you the actual char of the char array and *to_init is giving you a pointer to the first position of the char array. That's why the values are different.

Comment: Given the declaration `char **to_init;`, then the expression `**to_init` is __not__ a pointer.

Comment: `to_init` is a pointer to a pointer to a char. `*to_init` is a pointer to a char. `**to_init` is just a char.

Comment: When you use the operator * on the code (not on the declaration of the function)  you are actually getting the content of what the variable is pointing at. So:

to_int is char** -> *to_int is char * (because, char** points to char *) -> **to_int is char (because char * points to char)

Comment: Simply, use *(to_init +index) or to_init[index], this will get you what you the char *, that what to_init is pointing at

Comment: Ok we're getting somewhere, but earlier (before asking this) i tried *to_init[some_number]=character and my program kept crashing because it thought i was trying to modify to_init

Comment: meaning i had to change it to (*to_init)[number], even though *to_init[number] still gets my at **to_init

Comment: So what happened there

Comment: that's why i thought *to_init[0] and *to_init had to be the same due to that problem

Comment: *to_init[number] -> [] has precedence over * so your code was taking *(to_init + number), which is getting a value different of what you want because is only to_init that points where the data you want is, than taking the value of this position.

When you used the () the precedence goes to *to_init, which is pointing to char array you want, get this value and add the number then get the value of that position

Answer (score 1):

to_init[0] is the same as *to_init (a pointer to the char which to_init points to)
so *to_init[0] is the same as **to_init (the char) NOT *to_init (the pointer to char).

Answer (score 1):

`to_init` is of type `char**`, meaning a 'pointer to a pointer to a char'.

`*to_init` dereferences the variable, essentially getting the 'pointer to the char' of type `char*`.

Since the `[]` operator has [higher precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) than the `*` dereference, the first `char*` is dereferenced to a `char`. The first `printf` should therefore print a character value, not a pointer.

[As you can see here](https://eval.in/187996) this is correct - the first line returns hexadecimal `0x61`, which is the ASCII value for `a`. The second line returns a memory address, being the location of the compiled string value.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth oops, corrected - funnily result stays the same as it means you're dereferencing a `char*` to a char instead of returning the first char in a `char*`   :)

Answer (score 1):

They say a picture is worth a thousand words. Hopefully, the ASCII diagrams work as well as pictures.

Let's you have:

```
int A = 10;
int* ip = &ip;
int** ipp = &ipp;
```

The memory used by those variables look something like:

```
A
|
v
+----------------+
|    10          |
+----------------+

ip
|
v
+----------------+
| Address of A   |
+----------------+

ipp
|
v
+----------------+
| Address of ip  |
+----------------+
```

Now, let's look the exressions that are similar to what you are using:

```
*iip[0] = *(iip[0]) = *(ip) = 10
*iip = ip = Address of A
```

`*iip[0]` is not a memory address. It's the value of `A`.